# Typesafe wrapper function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I want to wrap my service methods in a `cachify` method that checks the cache before querying the database. However, I am unable to preserve the type declaration of the wrapped function.

The wrapping `cachify` function looks like this:

```js
// cache.ts
const cachify = async <T>(fn, args): Promise<T> => {
  const key = constructHashKey(args)
  const cachedEntry = get(key)

  if (cachedEntry) {
    return cachedEntry
  } else {
    const entry = await fn(...args)
    put(key, entry)
    return entry
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the usage of the wrapping function:

```js
// userService.ts
const getUserProfilePhotoUrl = async (id: string, size: string): Promise<string> => {
  return cachify<string>(fetchPhotoUrl, [
    id,
    size
  ])
}
```

The `fetchPhotoUrl` function has the signature `(id: string, size: string): Promise<string>`.

However, if I add some arbitrary argument to the array `[id, size]`, I do not get any type errors. How do I make Typescript aware of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the desired behavior you just need to add some type parameters to the function to capture the actual parameter types being passed in.

```
const cachify = async <T, A extends [any] | any[]>(fn: (...a: A) => Promise<T>, args: A): Promise<T> => {
    const key = constructHashKey(args)
    const cachedEntry = get(key)

    if (cachedEntry) {
        return cachedEntry
    } else {
        const entry = await fn(...args)
        put(key, entry)
        return entry
    }

}

declare function fetchPhotoUrl(id: string, size: string): Promise<string>;
const getUserProfilePhotoUrl = async (id: string, size: string): Promise<string> => {
    return cachify(fetchPhotoUrl, [
        id,
        size
    ])
}
```

If all you will be doing is just forwarding parameter along the this version might make things easier:

```
const cachify = <T, A extends [any] | any[]>(fn: (...a: A) => Promise<T>): ((...args: A) => Promise<T>) => {
    return async function (...args: A) {
        const key = constructHashKey(args)
        const cachedEntry = get(key)

        if (cachedEntry) {
            return cachedEntry
        } else {
            const entry = await fn(...args)
            put(key, entry)
            return entry
        }
    }
}

declare function fetchPhotoUrl(id: string, size: string): Promise<string>;
const getUserProfilePhotoUrl = cachify(fetchPhotoUrl)

getUserProfilePhotoUrl("id", "");
```

`getUserProfilePhotoUrl` is fully type safe, you get a tooltip for the parameter names if you hover over the function but not when in actual code completion (this should get fixed in the future).